# Saving MySQL spatial data Google maps API Bounds

Tags: mysql, google-maps-api-3, spatial

So I would like to save lat, lang and bounds spatial data to MySQL for now only to set a view port and zoom for places search. I saved lat, lang as POINT type and everything is fine but I'm stuck with bounds. I tried saving it as POLYGON but with no luck is it even a POLYGON? Inserting with PHPmyAdmin seems broken.. And I can't find straight forward explanation anywhere..

I tried inserting like that

```
(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 0 0))'))
```

And it went through but when I proper data MySQL throws warning about null values

```
(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((29.3772 60.517,38.490877 74.889862))'))
```

Also what's even more confusing is that rows get inserted even though column is set as NOT NULL.

Comment: A bounds is going to be a rectangle.  That can be represented as a POLYGON with 4 sides.  The examples in your question only have 2 points, not the required 4 (or 5 if you want to close the path).

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Never even heard of rectangle column type..